# Functional testing absolute links

Tags: url, symfony1, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

When I run functional tests in Symfony, my absolute links don't appear as they would even in the "real" test environment. For example, a link I output like this:

```
echo url_for("@homepage", true);
```

it will show up as `http://localhost/index.php/`, whereas if I actually visit the test site in my browser, it'll show up as `http://example.com.localhost/frontend_test.php/`

Now, I'm assuming this is happening because the test environment doesn't know anything about my local virtual server setup, etc., so it has no way of knowing what its "real" absolute URL should be.

But this makes my tests more difficult, and less "real". Making my tests pass by matching some odd link that wouldn't actually work if I were to click on it feels a bit wrong.

Maybe the best result would be if my test browser's absolute links looked the same as my real environment's absolute links, so I can easily test the results against the values that the real system would output, e.g. an absolute link to the homepage would look like it did in the live system:

```
http://example.com/
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

How do people normally deal with this? Can I "tell" the test browser where its absolute URLs should be based, in terms of hostname and controller, including dropping "index.php", and so get more realistic URLs out of the test framework?

(These URLs are being generated for an Atom feed and in emails, which is why I need them to be absolute. Relative links are working fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion your website should work with ANY domain. Testing for host name ties tests to it.

I think what you need is to check if the link is absolute or not (easily done with regexp).

I can hardly find a need for testing specific domain (unless you're using multiple domains; in such case domains should be configurable anyways).

**EDIT**:

You can actually change the host name with first parameter passed to the browser's constructor:

```
$test = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser('mydomain.com'));
```

I never tried it.

Comment: Thanks. It's possible that I'm heading down the wrong route due to not being that smart with using regexps with the tester. (I can use regular expressions okay, but I couldn't see an easy way of finding an element and checking the href attribute against a regexp,  e.g. validating `<link href="http://uniquesentence.com/index.php/sentence/feed" rel="self" />`. The examples for checkElement(), say, only use regexps on the element content, not on attributes. I'd also still have to ignore "index.php" on the URL, which would be an error if it happened on the live site...

Comment: In your case it might be indeed easier to verify the actual domain. Luckily it can be changed. See an update of my answer. My previous answer is still valid as you inject the domain now.

Comment: @Matt you can check attributes with eg `checkElement('link[rel=self]')` or `checkElement('link[href*=sentence]')` if that helps at all...

Comment: @Rich Yes, I'm happy enough with the CSS3 selector syntax, but it doesn't allow regexp checking, does it? At the moment I'm doing a few different tests like `checkElement('link[rel="self"][href^="http://"]')`... but it just seemed messy compared to using a single test with a regexp. I'd just assumed I was missing something, what with checking the *contents* of elements with a regexp being so trivial...

Comment: @Matt not that I'm aware of. I've only used the CSS3 ones myself. Sorry!

Comment: @Kuba Aha! I was just about to post that hostname trick myself, having dug through the sfBrowserBase code. That works well for the hostname (and I'd argue that it improves the testing as my tests now validate that absolute links are generated correctly from a given hostname by the routing classes.) Thanks for pointing that one out. I'm guessing I'll just have to live with the "index.php" on the end; perhaps there's no way of testing that that will be removed on the live site.

Comment: @richsage Incidentally, it's longwinded, but you *can* do it, as I've just discovered. Given my link example, and an sfTestFunctional `$b`: `$dom = $b->getResponseDom(); $xpath = new DomXPath($dom); $url = $xpath->query("//link[@rel='self']")->item(0)->getAttribute('href'); $b->test()->like($url, <regexp>)`... Shame there doesn't seem to be a shorthand like checkElementAttribute(), though.

Comment: @Matt nice, I like that, even if as you say it is longwinded. Sounds like a feature patch is necessary... ;-)